# Uncaught exception: "Could not convert JavaScript argument" nsresult: "0x80570009 (NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS)" line 150"

Tags: javascript, error-handling, cross-browser

I'm working on an open source project I'm part of called jQuery. I'm trying to get rid of an exception that makes the library partially work on Firefox and completely die in chrome:

> uncaught exception: [Exception... "Could not convert JavaScript argument" nsresult: "0x80570009 (NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS)" location: "JS frame :: http://dev.johnhamelink.com/jquery/jquewy/latest.js :: anonymous :: line 150" data: no]

I've tried to debug it, and I simply can't get my head around why it's creating an error like this. Any help would be much appreciated!

Edit: forgot to mention, you can view the code here: http://dev.johnhamelink.com/jquery/jquery/

John.

Comment: I changed it back to http for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I set a breakpoint in Firebug on the first line after the `addEvent` function declaration to see what was going on. I added watches for element, type, and callback.

- element = dom window object
- type = "load"
- callback= null

Problem is you are trying to set something to null that can not be set to null.

So you need to add a simple check for null in the addEvent method.

```
addEvent: function(element, type, callback){
    if(!callback) return;
    if(element.addEventListener) element.addEventListener(type, callback, false);
    else if(element.attachEvent) element.attachEvent('on'+type, callback);
}
```

Comment: That does remove the error. After doing a bit more debugging, it looks like something is stopping the loop that runs through the arguments from working, which is in turn causing the null value. What that is, I'm not sure yet.

Comment: Figure out the looping issue yet?

Comment: Yeah, that part works now. The only problem I have is getting the scripts and styles to execute on the broswer: http://dev.johnhamelink.com/jquery/jquewy/latest.js

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice cutting edge technology error here. Someone copied and pasted wrong.

```
else if(element.attachEvent) element.attachEvent('on'+element, callback);
```

Should be `'on'+type` not `'on'+element`.

Comment: Oops, I'm glad I never wrote that code! Unfortunately that doesn't fix the problem for me. Perhaps another "clue" is how chrome reacts: http://codepad.org/qv5KlTiK